# iOS possible memory issues with singletons in prefix header

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-management, singleton, prefix

I use a lot of singletons, I have set up many as I call them 'singleton frameworks'.

Also, I like to write the definition of the singleton in the prefix header of my XCode project, so I can use all my singletons in every class with only 1 line of code!
To me this seems like heaven, but I keep noticing that I have to deal a lot with memory warnings in all of my apps. So I was wondering, does that have anything to do with putting my singleton definitions in the prefix header? To me it seems since a singleton is only one instance it doesn't matter at all if you put it in the prefix header or not.
Perhaps it's more the fact that the 8 different singletons exist at the same time, each of them having different objects?

Here is an example of a regular prefix header in my projects:

```
//Imports
#import "Program.h"
#import "Category.h"
#import "GetSpecs.h"
#import "FlurryAPI.h"
#import "AdSmallView.h"
#import "SoundPlayer.h"
#import "ButtonAlert.h"
#import "NSViewHelper.h"
#import "NSDateHelper.h"
#import "NSStringHelper.h"
#import "TESTAppDelegate.h"
#import "EGORefreshTableHeaderView.h"

//Singletons
#define gSpecs [GetSpecs sharedGetSpecs]
#define bAlert [ButtonAlert sharedButtonAlert]
#define sPlayer [SoundPlayer sharedSoundPlayer]
#define adSmallV [AdSmallView sharedAdSmallView]
#define vHelper [NSViewHelper sharedNSViewHelper]
#define dateHelper [NSDateHelper sharedNSDateHelper]
#define nsprefs [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
#define strHelper [NSStringHelper sharedNSStringHelper]
#define pDel ((TESTAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
```

So to conclude, I have 2 questions: 
1. is it bad practice to put singleton definitions in the prefix header?
2. can memory issues be caused by this prefix header part or is it more possible it's the fact that many different singletons are continuously 'alive'?

Comment: You should really write the kind of memory warnings you get. About the 1st question, since you are using #define, it probably really just "substitutes" the code down below, but you are constantly using the sharedXXX method, not the most efficient way... Call it once on the beginning, save it in a variable, and use it till the end, seems more efficient. The 2nd question, memory warnings/problems needed and also your singleton template would be nice.

Comment: "(I hate writing the same lines of code over and over) so I love to make one singleton and use it everywhere." You're kidding us, right?

Comment: The memory warnings could be caused by having so many different singleton instances floating around. Unless you explicitly release them somewhere, once accessed they will remain in memory until the application exists. There is a time and a place for singletons, and you should consider whether your design pattern is correct for mobile devices with low memory, where lazily-loading things and releasing-when-done is generally preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting approach. It's not a problem to have these as `#define`s in the precompiled header-- this does make them available everywhere, and as jtbandes says, they are only invoked on usage anyways, so no memory concerns there.

It strikes me as stylistically a little goofy that you're essentially creating global "magic" reserved words that look like they could be local variable names. If others are reading your code, they're not especially self-explanatory. If doing this, I would probably at least start them with a capital or make them all-caps to indicate they're a definition/macro.

It's also a little unorthodox to be pulling so many app headers into the precompiled header (which is normally quite lean, and used for core system stuff), but the actual effects on compile time here on modern machines will be totally negligible.

---

Your statements about why you create singletons, and memory warnings, lead me to think that you may still be learning programming. Singletons are fine way in an object oriented world to encapsulate an object that should only exist once. If you're using them as a way to avoid "writing the same code over and over", any regular function or method where you need it will work as well. For "helpers", you should look into "categories" as well which might do some of the lifting for you there. Re: the 8 different singletons. Zillions of objects coexist at the same time while your app is running, singletons and otherwise. That alone is not an issue-- they don't bother eachother as long as they're all managed correctly.

Comment: Hi quixoto, thanks for your response. It's true I'm still new to the objective-c world. I've learned Java/Matlab 4 years long but started iPhone/iPad programming just a year ago. I do love the language, but I'm still learning the best design patterns I guess. The answers here lead me to believe that the prefix header is not the problem, but the singletons all alive at once might. I guess I should go back and see whether I really need some singletons, categories can definitely replace some of my helpers! Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Since these are macros, whenever you use them, it's just like if you had actually typed `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` or any of the others, so there's no risk of keeping more singletons alive, because the prefix header is not actually creating the singletons.

I wouldn't say it's bad practice; I've done it before. However, I might recommend instead putting these definitions in the class headers themselves, like putting `pDel` in `TESTAppDelegate.h`, so that if you `#import TESTAppDelegate.h` you can use it. It will probably make your program compile faster if you don't `#import` lots of headers in the prefix header (because those will be imported for every file).